# Traveling Karachi Pakistan on Expired NICOP + online Renewal Slip

Tags: canada, pakistan

Does anybody have experience enter and exit on expired National Identity Card for Overseas Pakistanis (NICOP) + renewal Slip? Already ask PIA, they will let me board but question is

- Can we come back to Canada same way with expired NICOP and renewal slip?

Toronto Consulate have no idea about coming back on renewal slip.

Comment: What is your itinerary?

Comment: @farhan Can you clarify your question? It reads to me as if ‘can we come back’ might refer to returning to Pakistan or Canada

Comment: @Traveller return to Canada

Comment: @farhan In that case, is your concern about entering and exiting Pakistan, or entering Canada (or both?) What is your Immigration status in Canada? And will your passport / other relevant travel document(s) be valid on your planned return date? https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html

Comment: If the OP also wants to know about re-entering Canada, this post isn't a duplicate of the question cited in Comments above.

Comment: I have valid Canadian passport. Only concern is entering and exiting after one month from Pakistan at Pakistani Airport with Expired NICOP and renewal slip.. 
Reason asking as return back to Canada  at Pakistan Airport they also check NICOP and Passport (with entry Stamp).